# How to check for visibility if the class exists in capybara?

Tags: ruby, capybara, minitest

With capybara and minitest, how would you check for visibility of a element if the element exists on the page? The class isn't always guaranteed to be there, so I need to check if it is on the page first.

All I can think of is:

```
assert find(".class-name").visible? if has_css?(".class-name", :wait=>0)
```

Are there any other ways of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

By default Capybara only finds visible elements, so

```
if has_css?(".class-name", wait: 0)
```

will only return true if the element is visible on the page

If you want to verify the element is either not on the page, or if it is in the source of the page it must be visible then you could do something like

```
assert_css('.class-name') if has_css?('.class-name', visible: :all)
```

or just

```
refute_css('.class-name', visible: :hidden) # ensure there is no non-visible element with the class name
```